# iOS - How to detect a session timeout on UIWebView

Tags: ios, session, uiwebview, timeout, connection

I have a UIWebView displaying a website that has a timeout policy (idle for 1800 seconds).
Since I use a custom login view to connect to the site, I want to call this same custom view after the website has issued the timeout alert.

How can I detect that such an alert has been issued to the webview, so I can call my code from there?

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 1):

If the website redirects to a particular page on timeout, you could watch for that page to be loaded in your UIWebViewDelegate's `webView:shouldStartLoadWithRequest:navigationType:` method.

Comment: I ended up using the webViewDidFinishLoading delegate method. Here I check if the method was called due to a time out (I can check the timer from the website).

Answer (score 0):

Don't know how to solve this from UIKit perspective but if your session time out is known you could create an NSTimer in one of your controllers to alert you when a defined elapsed time, resetting it each time the app calls your site[.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1032776/countdown-timer)